# Strong and Weak Convergence of standard normal i.i.d

Tags: probability

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be standard normal i.i.d and set $M_n=\max_{j\leq n} X_j$. Let $a_n\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $F_{X_j}(a_n)=(n-1)/n$ where $F_{X_j}$ is the distribution function. Prove the following

(a) $a_n(M_n-a_n) \Rightarrow M$ (convergence weakly to random variable $M$) where $M$ has distribution $F_M=e^{-e^{-x}}$

(b)$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_n}{\sqrt{2\log n}}=1$

(c)$\frac{M_n}{\sqrt{2\log n}}$ converges to 1 in probability

To start (a), I want to show that the characteristic function of $a_n(M_n-a_n)$ converges to the characteristic of $M$. Or the distribution of $a_n(M_n-a_n)$ converges to $F_M$. They don't look very straightforward. Also, whats the relation between $a_n$ and $M_n$. I know that $M_n\geq X_n$ for every $n$ and since $X_n$ are i.i.d we can conclude that $\varphi_{M_n}=\varphi_{X_n}^n$ (If I m right). Any ideas, hints? I think once we figure out the relation between $M_n$ and $a_n$, the problem becomes easy. Thanks